# rake gives an error about an uninitialized constant Consolidated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a rails app written by a friend of mine and when I run rake db:setup I get the following error - I am running on debian using rvm to run ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.1.0 Can anyone point me in the right directon to solve this? Why is the migration trying to use a constant thats undefined? Do I need to define it somewhere? I am not a rails dev so this has me stumped.

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant Consolidated
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:43:in `constantize'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:517:in `load_migration'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:512:in `migration'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:507:in `migrate'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:687:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `call'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:686:in `block in migrate'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:671:in `each'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:671:in `migrate'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:549:in `up'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:530:in `migrate'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:161:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```